# Correctly dealing with closures and modularity in Javascript

Tags: javascript, modules, closure

The code below is designed to deal with this situation:

> There is a **Battle** environment with **Characters**; these Characters obviously have certain characteristics and abilities, and they need to be able to use **Items** from an inventory.

I would like as much feedback as possible on the various aspects of the code:

- **The approach to the problem**: did I make something that was simple, overly complex?
- **The cleanliness/readability of the code**: is the code readable and understandable? Am I following the best practices? (Spaces/Tabs/Operator alignment/Brackets…)
- **Code syntax**: am I `return`ing correctly? Am I missing some tests that I should do?

On the other hand, I have some very specific questions:

1. Am I handling closures correctly? My approach has been to try to be as modular as possible, creating one `global object` to hold all my properties, and creating modules inside *iife*s.
2. I had encountered a problem especially when dealing with **Constructors** inside the closures. Obviously they are not accessible from the outside with the usual syntax, making it impossible for me to create new Objects in different modules. I solved this problem in the `Character` constructor by actually adding the function to a variable of the `Battle` global object, as I would do for a *method*. That, however, **doesn't feel right**.
3. In the **Items module** the goal is to define the various available items in a *dictionary*-like `object` or `array` to later add to the `Battle` global object. Does this approach make sense? Adding objects to the `array` the way I do, poses a little problem, though, as the variables lose their name.
4. That brings me to the way I solved this problem (which perhaps is unnecessary in the first place) in the **Character module**. Because I want the syntax of the `useItem(item)` method to accept `item` as a `string` of the name of the item, I go a bit around in loops to find out the corresponding object using the array `filter()` method. Is this the right way of finding what I am looking for? Would I just be better off by referring to the items as their `array index` in the *dictionary*?
5. **Redundancy**: in the `useItem()` method, after checking if the character owns the particular item he's trying to use inside an `if` statement which `returns false`, I add an `else`. Given the fact that the function **returns** if the conditions are met, is it redundand to add an `else`? I don't know why, but it felt **safer** to add it.
6. As for the way that **Characters** are handled, would I be better off having the characters in a numbered `array` then having them being handled by their variable names? Especially considering that the **Battle initialisation module** is just an example and, ideally, will extract data from an XML or a JSON.

"Extra" questions:

- **Documentation**: I am always confused by best practices on how to document code, especially when it is Javascript (at least PHP as some more consolidated best practices).
- **Dev tools**: both Chrome and Firefox behave differently in the way they handle the *debugging* statements.

  1. For some reason, Chrome doesn't display an integer when it's 0, while Firefox does.
  2. On the other hand, Firefox doesn't correctly substitute the strings when encountering things such as `%2$s` and `%ss`. Am I using those incorrectly?
  3. In [this article of the Chrome Dev Tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#string_substitution_and_formatting), they show that, when using string substitution, the variables get colored in blue, which aids readability quite a lot. My dev tools are not working as such, showing it all in black: am I missing something or this has been changed since the documentation has been written? I know that I can style the whole message with `%c`, but I don't think that's what happens in that article section.

<kbd>[**Working code**](http://jsbin.com/ikenaq/2/edit)</kbd>

**Global JS**

```
/*
 * Initialising the container global object
 */

var Battle = {
  itemDefinitions: [],
  characters:      {}
};
```

**Item module**

```
(function(Battle){

  /*
   * Item constructor
   *
   * Defines a new Item object.
   *
   * @param  string  name             The name of the item;
   * @param  string  result           The effect of the item;
   * @param  string  augmentedResult  The effect of the item if the user's
   *                                  support is 'experiment'
   */

  function Item(name, result, augmentedResult){
    this.name            = name;
    this.result          = result;
    this.augmentedResult = augmentedResult;
  }

  // Here come the items
  var potion   = new Item('Potion',    '+50 hp',  '+100 hp');
  var hiPotion = new Item('Hi Potion', '+125 hp', '+150hp');

  // Put all the created items in an array for easier iteration
  var itemDefinitions = [potion, hiPotion];

  // Populate the global object with item Definitions
  itemDefinitions.forEach(function(entry, idx){
    Battle.itemDefinitions.push(entry);
  });


})(Battle);
```

**Character module**

```
(function(Battle){

  /*
   * Character constructor
   *
   * Defines a new Character object.
   *
   * @param  string  name     The name of the character;
   * @method mixed   useItem  Uses an item from the character's inventory;
   */

  Battle.Character = function Character(name){
    this.name = name;
  };

  /*
   * Uses an item from the character's inventory.
   *
   * This method checks if the character has the item available in
   * his inventory. If he does, it uses the item to the best of the
   * character's ability.
   *
   * @param  string  item  The name of the item to use;
   * @return mixed         Returns false if the item could not be used
   *                       otherwise, returns the item's effect;
   */

  Battle.Character.prototype.useItem = function(item) {
    var itemType, ownedItem, result;

    // Checks if the requested item has been defined in the
    // items dictionary
    itemType = Battle.itemDefinitions.filter(function(obj){
        return obj.name === item;
    });

    itemType = itemType.length === 0 ? null : itemType[0];

    if( itemType === null ) {
      console.error('Invalid item type “%s”: item does not exist', item);
      return false;
    }

    // Checks if the user has enough of those items in his
    // inventory
    ownedItem = this.inventory.filter(function(obj){
      return obj.name === item;
    });

    ownedItem = ownedItem.length === 0 ? null : ownedItem[0];

    if( ownedItem === null || ownedItem.quantity <= 0 ) {
      console.error('Cannot complete action: not enough %ss', item);
      return false;
    } else {
      // Defines the item's effect according to the user's
      // actual ability
      if ( this.support === 'experiment' )
          result = itemType.augmentedResult;
      else
          result = itemType.result;

      // Removes one of the said item from the user's inventory
      // and logs the result.
      ownedItem.quantity--;
      console.log('%s used %s: %s; \n%d %2$s remaining.',
                  this.name,
                  item,
                  result,
                  ownedItem.quantity);
    }

  };

})(Battle);
```

**Battle initialisation module**

```
/*
 * Battle initialisation
 *
 * This would ideally get data from an external source.
 */

(function(Battle){

  var carl = new Battle.Character('Carl');
  carl.inventory = [
    { 
      name:     'Potion',
      quantity: 2
    },
    {
      name:     'Eyedrop',
      quantity: 1
    }];
  carl.support = 'experiment';

  var jerry = new Battle.Character('Jerry');
  jerry.inventory = [
    {
      name:     'Hi Potion',
      quantity: 1
    }
  ];

  Battle.characters.carl  = carl;
  Battle.characters.jerry = jerry;

})(Battle);
```

**Battle execution**

```
/*
 * Battle execution
 *
 * Just a quick example of what happens when
 * the defined functions are run.
 */

Battle.characters.carl.useItem('Potion');
Battle.characters.carl.useItem('Potion');
Battle.characters.carl.useItem('Potion');
Battle.characters.jerry.useItem('Hi Potion');
```

Comment: I would structure `Battle` as more of a namespace, right now you have it as a catch-all. I don't have much time to go into more detail now, but I'll try to find some time in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

As Shmiddty said, you want your `Battle` object to be more of a namespace providing access to the modules:

```
var Battle = function () {}

Battle.Character = (function (/* dependencies */) {

  // constructor
  var Character = function (name) {
     this.name = name;
  };

  // instance method
  Character.prototype.useItem = function () {
     [...]
  };

  // private method
  var soSomething = function () {
     [...]
  };

  return Character;

}(/* dependencies */));
```